# JQuery - How to find the next occurence of element with specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a table like this:

```
<table id="TblProduits" class="TblProduitsLayout">
    <thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="placeholderRow">
                <td>
                    <input class="PrixUnitr" type="number" />
                </td> 
            <tr class="placeholderRow">
            <tr class="placeholderRow SousTotal">
                <td>
                    <input  class="MontnHT" type="text" disabled="disabled"  min="0"/>
                </td>
            <tr class="placeholderRow">
            <tr class="placeholderRow SousTotal">
                <td>
                    <input  class="MontnHT" type="text" disabled="disabled" min="0">
                </td>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to change the value of the fisrt occurence of the `input` with classname `MontnHT` contained inside a `tr` with classname `SousTotal` when the value of the `input` with classname `PrixUnitr` is changed, so I created an event  like this:

```
$('body').on('change', '.PrixUnitr', function() {       
    $(this).closest('tr').nextAll("tr.SousTotal").find("input.MontnHT").val("foo");
});
```

My problem is that is also changes the other inputs contained inside a `TR` with the same classname `SousTotal` , as I want to change just the first occurence , what am I doing wrong? and how can it be fixed?

Comment: `.next("tr.SousTotal")` or `.find("input.MontnHT:first")`

Comment: Read what nextAll does in the documentation https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/

Comment: I already tried .next() it does just check the next tr element , and does not continue exploring the rest

Comment: I already checked nextAll() , and I know it is not maybe the best thing to work with here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `.first()` or `.eq(0)` to get the first occurrence of the element

```
 $(this).closest('tr').nextAll("tr.SousTotal").first().find("input.MontnHT:first").val("foo");
```

or

```
 $(this).closest('tr').nextAll("tr.SousTotal:eq(0)").find("input.MontnHT:eq(0)").val("foo");
```

Comment: I did not think it was this easy, I spent 2 hours with this, You are a beast my good sir (y)